# word press admin end Broken links not going to solve

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, broken-links

I have installed Broken Links Checker plugin, it's showing 638 links broken 
Into frontend, the links are working fine after click on showing links into the broken lists.
Same its working fine into the admin end just showing the lists of the broken links 
The problem comes after moving the site to the new domain

**Steps I have followed:-**

1. Correct the path of the site URL and home URL from HTTP to https as my site working with SSL
2. Deactivate all the plugins from Cpanel.
3. Rename theme name and activate another theme into the admin
4. I have to make correction into the database with all the links from HTTP to https
5. The links are working correctly just its showing the list of links into the admin end please check the screenshot:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to permanently 301 redirect all HTTP links to HTTPS.

You need to add the redirect rule in the `.htaccess` file.
Then clear any cache and update the permalinks.